# Show that a bounded subset of a normed vector space is in a closed ball

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

Let $E$ be a normed vector space and $A$ be a non-empty bounded subset of $E$. 
Let $I = \{R \in \mathbb{R}^+, A \subset \mathcal{B}(x,R), x\in E\}$. Let $r = \inf I$.

The goal is to show that $A \subset \mathcal{B}(x,r)$ where $x\in E$.

1. I started to show that $I$ is non-empty set and that $r$ does exist. I have shown it using a proof by contradiction. If $I$ is empty then $A$ is not bounded.
2. I have defined $R_n=r + \frac{1}{n}$. I must show that there exists $x_n \in E$ such that $A \in \mathcal{B}(x_n, R_n)$. I don't know how to prove it since it seems intuitive that a smaller radius of the ball implies that $x_n$ is closer from $A$.
3. Then I've shown that $(x_n)$ is bounded (again by contradiction). I have to deduce that there exists a convergent subsequence. I immediately thought about Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, but I need to prove that $E$ is a compact set to use the theorem, and I don't see how to prove it. I also thought about the fact that in a normed vector set, closed balls are compact sets but I couldn't progress any further than that.
4. Finally I have to show that $A \subset \mathcal{B}(x,r)$ where $x\in E$, where $x$ is the limit of the convergent subsequence. Here is the beginning of my proof for that one but I block at some point:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. 
$\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N_1, \lvert\lvert x_{\phi{n}} - x \rvert  \rvert < \epsilon$. 
$\exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N_2, \lvert R_{\phi(n)} - r \rvert < \epsilon$. 
Let $N_3 = \max(N_1, N_2)$ and $y \in A$.

$$ \lvert\lvert x-y \rvert\rvert \leq \lvert\lvert x - x_{\phi(n)}\rvert\rvert + \lvert\lvert x_{\phi(n)} - y\rvert\rvert $$
$$ \lvert\lvert x-y \rvert\rvert \leq \epsilon + R_{\phi(n)}$$

All in all, I think I have the intuition for the exercise. I can make a drawing of it on a sheet of paper but I can't really formalize the proof.

Answer (score 1):

1. "$E$ is a compact set". NO. The only compact normed vector space is the trivial space $\{0\}$.
2. "In a normed vector set, closed balls are compact". NO. This is only true in finite-dimensional normed vector spaces.
3. The main result may be false if $E$ is not a Banach space. For example let $E$ be the set of continuous piece-wise linear $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ with the $\sup$ norm $\|f-g\|=\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|.$ Let $A=\{f\in E: \forall x\in [0,1]\,(|f(x)-x^2|\le 1)\}.$ For every $s>1$ there is an open $E$-ball of radius $s$ that covers $A.$ But even a closed $E$-ball $\overline {B(f,1)}$ cannot cover $A,$ else $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in [0,1],$ but then $f\not \in E.$

Comment: I'm willing to say more but I just woke up & wanted to write my thoughts from yesterday.

Comment: Yes, sure ! Go on !